# NSNumberFormatter bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I try to convert the NSString `@"8.8"` to a NSNumber by NSNumberFormatter

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"###0.##"];

NSNumber *result = [formatter numberFromString:@"8.8"];
NSLog(@"%@", [result stringValue]);
[formatter release];
```

the result is `8.800000000000001`.

For any other value (i.e: `6.6`, `7.7`, `9.9`, `1.2`, `4.7` etc.), the logged result was exactly the same NSString passed to `numberFromString` method.

I'm using XCode 4.1 and the 4.3 simulator. There is no difference if I put (or not) `setMaximumFractionDigits` or/and `setPositiveFormat`, the result is always `8.800000000000001`. What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most numbers that are not integers can not be represented accurately in floating point variables.  There is a class `NSDecimalNumber` that handles exact values at a cost of overhead, this is mainly used for monetary calculations.

See: [WIkipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

Floating point numbers are rational numbers because they can be represented as one integer divided by another. The base however determines the fractions that can be represented. For instance, 1/5 cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number using a binary base but can be represented exactly using a decimal base.